# div inside echo function

Tags: php, echo

i have this

```
<?php
            } // if ( $coupons )

            do_action('st_after_coupon_listings');
            echo wpcoupon_store()->get_extra_info();

            wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```

and i want to `get_extra_info()` inside of `<div class="mydiv"></div>`

I tried

```
echo "<div class="mydiv">;
echo wpcoupon_store()->get_extra_info();
echo "</div>";
```

but this did not work.

I am making mistakes somewhere in syntax, it would mean a lot if someone could help.

Comment: Hello. Stack Overflow is not the place to fix syntax issues. You are correct this is a syntax issue. Look careful at your opening and closing brackets, quotes, tags, and other opening and closing elements when you have isssues like this. Also, error messages when enabled will tell you what line the syntax issue causes problems. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you want to echo in double quotes, then the double quotes you want displayed need to be escaped.. `echo "<div class=\"mydiv\">";`  but since there are no variables there to translate, use single quotes 
`echo '<div class="mydiv">';`

Comment: @ Goose right on. 

@DuaneLortie i picked the second one. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a syntax error, you missed a quote`"` replace the bottom code with

```
echo '<div class="mydiv">';
echo wpcoupon_store()->get_extra_info();
echo '</div>';
```

or if you wish to keep the outer quotes constant you could use

```
echo "<div class=\"mydiv\">";
echo wpcoupon_store()->get_extra_info();
echo "</div>";
```

but this is a bit harder to read

Comment: First one worked! Second one causes an error. Thanks!